# Returning Multiple Property Bags in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, scom

I'm trying to return two values from my VBScript and stored them in separate property bags:

1. Contains the result of the `If` condition

   ```
       Call oBag.AddValue("Status","Bad")
       Call objAPI.AddItem(oBag)
   Else
       Call oBag.AddValue("Status","Good")
       Call objAPI.AddItem(oBag)
   ```
2. Contains the output of the SQL query that been executed

   ```
   Call oBag.AddValue("Count",objRS.Fields("CountStuff"))
   Call objAPI.AddItem(oBag)
   ```

for passing on next to SCOM.

But while debugging, I'm getting the following error:

> (41,1) ADODB.Field: Either BOF or EOF is True, or the current record has beed deleted. Requsted operation requires a current record.

Here is the full VBScript:

```
Dim objCN, strConnection
Dim objAPI, oBag

Set objCN = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objAPI = CreateObject("MOM.ScriptAPI")
Set oBag = objAPI.CreateTypedPropertyBag(2)

strConnection = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=SCOMSRVDB01,2880;Database=DBABee;Trusted_Connection=TRUE"
objCN.Open strConnection

Dim strSQLQuery
strSQLQuery = "Select COUNT (*) as CountStuff from sys.objects"

Dim objRS
Set objRS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Set objRS = objCN.Execute(strSQLQuery)

'WScript.Echo (objRS.Fields("CountStuff"))
Call oBag.AddValue("Count", objRS.Fields("CountStuff"))
Call objAPI.AddItem(oBag)

Do Until objRS.EOF
    'WScript.Echo objRS.Fields("CountStuff")
    If objRS.Fields("CountStuff") > 0 Then
        'WScript.Echo "evaluated as bad"
        Call oBag.AddValue("Status","Bad")
        Call objAPI.AddItem(oBag)
    Else
        Call oBag.AddValue("Status","Good")
        Call objAPI.AddItem(oBag)
     End If
     objRS.MoveNext
Loop

Call objAPI.ReturnItems
objRS.Close

'Property[@Name='Status']
```

Comment: Your code is missing a check that `objRS.EOF <> True` befor calling `Call oBag.AddValue("Count", objRS.Fields("CountStuff"))`

Comment: Thanks Ansgar Wiechers, i don't need to change anything in the loop itself?

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems to be pretty straightforward. You need to use the `MoveFirst` method to move the current record position to the first record in the `objRS` recordset.

However, a call to either `MoveFirst` or `MoveLast` generates an error when the `objRS` recordset is empty (both `BOF` and `EOF` are `True`). Hence, call it *conditionally* as follows:

```
''' ''' '''
If Not ( objRS.BOF And objRS.EOF ) Then objRS.MoveFirst

Do Until objRS.EOF
    'WScript.Echo objRS.Fields("CountStuff")
    If objRS.Fields("CountStuff") > 0 Then
        'WScript.Echo "evaluated as bad"
        Call oBag.AddValue("Status","Bad")
        Call objAPI.AddItem(oBag)
    Else
        Call oBag.AddValue("Status","Good")
        Call objAPI.AddItem(oBag)
     End If
     objRS.MoveNext
Loop
''' ''' '''
```

Resource: [MoveFirst, MoveLast, MoveNext, and MovePrevious Methods (ADO)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/movefirst-movelast-movenext-and-moveprevious-methods-ado)

Comment: Thanks JosefZ, i update the script following your instructions, and i see the query result (**72**) in the script output: **<DataItem type="System.PropertyBagData" time="2018-03-27T14:17:11.3661896+03:00"
sourceHealthServiceId="6041F260-B314-9D7F-A55F-2AFBF08939DC"><Property Name="Co
unt" VariantType="9">72</Property></DataItem>** But that means that only 1 Property Bag has been successfully populated with the value of the SQL query that been executed. What about the second Property Bag that supposed to Contains the result of the `If `condition?

Comment: @edwio `Select COUNT (*) as CountStuff from sys.objects`: the `COUNT (*)` function returns the total number of rows in the `sys.objects` table i.e. the only number. Maybe something like `Select *, COUNT (*) as CountStuff from sys.objects GROUP BY something`?

Comment: i think you misunderstood me. i'm well aware for the `COUNT (*)` function. the only thing that i'm trying to accomplish at this moment. is to populate the `IF` contidon (Bad/Good) to another Property Bag.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send only one PropertyBag DataItem you shouldn't add it to Collection.

```
Set oBag = Call objAPI.CreatePropertyBag()
If Not (objRS.BOF And objRS.EOF) Then
  objRS.MoveFirst
  Call oBag.AddValue("CountStuff", objRS.Fields("CountStuff"))
  Call objAPI.Return(oBag)
End If
Call objRS.Close()
```

And better to compare Bad/Good states in System.ExpressionFilter if it hasn't hard boolean logic:

```
<Expression>
  <SimpleExpression>
    <ValueExpression>
      <XPathQuery Type="Integer">Property[@Name="CountStuff"]</XPathQuery>
    </ValueExpression>
    <Operator>Greater</Operator>
    <ValueExpression>
      <Value Type="Integer">0</Value>
    </ValueExpression>
  </SimpleExpression>
</Expression>
```